# How to make characters non editable in primefaces inputmask

Tags: jsf, primefaces

First two characters should be non editable.

Example: input string length has to be 4:  text box "TEXT"

User can change only "XT" not "TE";

Edited: TEXT can AAAA, aaaa, aa90, 9a09, String can be anything.

User can change only last two character and first two character could be anything.

We can use p:inputtext or p:inputmask

Thanks

Comment: Grammar, understandability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text can be anything and the first 2 characters need to be fixed, you don't have any other option then to make your mask dynamic and base it on the value of the variable.

```
<p:inputMask value="#{bean.value}" mask="#{bean.mask}" />
```

And in your bean in the getter (or lazy after the setter of the value is called), replace the last two characters with a '*'

```
value | mask
----- | ----
 TEXT | TE**
 AAAA | AA**
 aaaa | aa**
 aa90 | aa**
 9a09 | 9a**
```

And if the existing definitions (a, 9 and *) are blocking things in your case (as they seem to do), you can remove them from the definitions by using

```
$.mask.definitions['a']= "";
$.mask.definitions['9']= "";
```

and if the definition of the '*' is to narrow (default: [a-z|A-Z|0-9]), you can change it to anything you like by using regular expressions:

```
$.mask.definitions['*']= "[\\S]"
```

This e.g. meaning any non-whitespace character, so #, % etc are allowed to;

You can create your [own definitions too](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

### Security note:

Keep in mind, this is a **client-side** mask. There is **no server-side validation to it**. If a user tampers with the allowed mask or value of the input, the server will not block it. No idea if it should, but for the moment it does not!

Note to self: Never used this component, but again the [PrimeFaces sourcecode](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L2936), the [jquery-mask-plugin](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery/jquery-plugins.js#L13135) and the [documentation of the mask library](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) helped here... The source is your friend

Comment: It`s work for me by apply j query $.mask.definitions['a']= ""; $.mask.definitions['9']= ""; thanks a lot, But, if user give three character whole word goes disappear. like "99w". it has to be 4 character like "99w3"

Comment: That is a limitation of the underlying jquery mask plugin afaik. Maybe check there...