# p:inputMask - how to customize the mask characters e.g. force input to capitalize certain letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, input-mask

I would like to force input to capitalize a letter in certain position of text using p:inputMask. In *jquery-plugins.js* one can find following definition: `a: "[A-Za-z]"`. My goal is to get something like: `a: "[a-z]", A: "[A-Z]"`.
Is it possible to get this without big and maybe harmful changes in PrimeFaces source code?

Comment: could you provide a link to the definition you mention?

Comment: See here: you can create your own definitions

Comment: Link to definition: primefaces-5.3-sources\META-INF\resources\primefaces\jquery\jquery-plugins.js - line: 13091.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the existing definitions (a, 9,*) are not sufficient, you can add your own ones. You can change it to anything you like by using regular expressions by putting this in your page:

```
$.mask.definitions['*']= "[\\S]"
```

This e.g. meaning any non-whitespace character, so #, % etc are allowed to;

```
$.mask.definitions['A']= "[A-Z]"
$.mask.definitions['a']= "[a-z]"
```

Make 'a' require lowercase and 'A' uppercase

**See also**

- [How to make characters non editable in primefaces inputmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843128/how-to-make-characters-non-editable-in-primefaces-inputmask)

Comment: The source and the internet was my help... I never used this component, but the source helped me